# php function global not working anonymous

Tags: php

I use a function in anonymous function in function but not working global in the first function!

```
function Runing($fun){
    $fun();
}

Runing(function (){
    $a = 22;
    function matchFunc (){
        global $a;
        return $a + 1;
    }
    echo matchFunc();
    //Result : 1
});
```

I want the result 23 !

Comment: Not sure why you want to use a global in the first place.  But `$a` isn't global as you have defined it in the closure.

Comment: `global $a` doesn't work because `$a` isn't global! Global means "not inside any function or other block". But your $a is inside a function. It's unclear what the structure is supposed to be achieving, but either http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/018b36a6db907bc5a2d9df394c66fd05cbe91218 or http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/06826675cc70670c596a2303fc40d678279b6c9d would get you the expected result, with different structures. As I say though, it's unclear which is suitable for your scenario or indeed what the real purpose of these nested functions is meant to be.